# How to split argument/message

Tags: java

Need help in making regular expression to split some argument/messages. I got this argument/messages

```
DynaActionForm[dynaClass=fbDetailInterTransfer,beneficiaryBank=000014,transactionReference=,beneReferenceNo=,terminationDate=,payFrequency=,beneficiaryResident=,amount=10000000,selectedDateTermination=,currencyCode=,selectedMonthTermination=,beneficiaryId=,paymentType=,payFrequencyCode=,fromAccount=0,selectedMonth=,effectiveDateRecurring=,toAccountHolderName=,selectedDate=,payMode=1,selectedYearTermination=,toAccount=3403571268,segment=,remarks=,effectiveDate=,checkBeneficiaryId=,emailAddress=,selectedYear=,beneficiaryIdType=]
```

I need to split that argument/message in order to get only this argument/message

```
beneficiaryBank=000014
amount=10000000
toAccount=3403571268
```

What regex in order to get the result above?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers.  At least, you should have tried something yourself, and ideally show some **code** of what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work - [a-zA-Z]+=[0-9]+
Make it a capturing group like ([a-zA-Z]+=[0-9]+). Iterate on that and get the desired result.

```
    Pattern prPattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+=[0-9]+)");

    Matcher prMatcher = prPattern.matcher(input);

    while (prMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(prMatcher.group(1));
    }
```

**Output:**

```
beneficiaryBank=000014
amount=10000000
fromAccount=0
payMode=1
toAccount=3403571268
```